# How sort $item values for title inside a foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-order-by, codeigniter-3

I'd display the values in sorting order by title. It shows the values sorting only by page_order, I edited Page_model->get_pages() order_by('page_order') to order_by('title') but it continues to display by page_order. I can't seem to find an answer on this topic. How can I sort the values by title in the following code:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($menu_links as $item): 
        if ($item['parent_id'] != "0" && $item['subcat_recip_id'] != "" ):
?>

<?php 
            $valuesub = explode(",",$item['subcat_recip_id']);
            foreach($valuesub as $dt):
                if (html_escape("$dt") == html_escape("$subrecp")):
?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo html_escape($item["slug"]);?>?subrecp=<?php echo html_escape("$subrecp"); ?>"><?php echo html_escape($item["title"]) ?></a></li> 
<?php 
                endif; 
            endforeach;
?>
<?php 
        endif; 
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Recipes Model

```
* recipes Page
 */
public function recipes()
{
    $this->load->model('page_model');
    $data['page'] = $this->page_model->get_page('recipes');
    if ($data['page']->page_active == 0) {
        $this->error_404();
    } else {
        $data['title'] = get_page_title($data['page']);
        $data['description'] = get_page_description($data['page']);
        $data['keywords'] = get_page_keywords($data['page']);
        $data['page_settings'] = get_page_settings();
        $data['menu_links'] = $this->navigation_model->get_menu_links();
    $this->load->view('partials/_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('recipes', $data);
    $this->load->view('partials/_footer');
    }
}
```

Navigation_model->get_Menu_links

```
 public function get_menu_links()
 {
     $menu = array();
     $pages = $this->page_model->get_pages();
     if (!empty($pages)) {
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $page_type = "page";
            if (!empty($page->link)) {
                $page_type = "link";
            }
            $item = array(
                'order' => $page->page_order,
                'id' => $page->id,
                'lang_id' => $page->lang_id,
                'parent_id' => $page->parent_id,
                'subcat_recip_id' => $page->subcat_recip_id,
                'title' => $page->title,
                'slug' => $page->slug,
                'link' => lang_base_url() . $page->slug,
                'type' => $page_type,
                'location' => $page->location,
                'visibility' => $page->page_active,
                        'subcat_recip_id' => $page->subcat_recip_id,
            );

            if ($page_type == "link") {
                $item["link"] = $page->link;
            }
            if ($page->slug == "index") {
                $item["link"] = lang_base_url();
            }

            array_push($menu, $item);
        }
    }

    $categories = $this->category_model->get_categories();
    if (!empty($categories)) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $item = array(
                'order' => $category->category_order,
                'id' => $category->id,
                'lang_id' => $category->lang_id,
                'parent_id' => $category->parent_id,
                'title' => $category->name,
                'slug' => $category->slug,
                'link' => lang_base_url() . "category/" . $category->slug,
                'type' => "category",
                'location' => "header",
                'visibility' => $category->show_on_menu,
                        'subcat_recip_id' => $page->subcat_recip_id,
            );
            array_push($menu, $item);
        }
    }

    sort($menu);
    return $menu;
}
```

Page_model->get_pages

```
//get pages
public function get_pages()
{
    $this->db->where('pages.lang_id', $this->selected_lang->id);
    $this->db->order_by('page_order');
    $query = $this->db->get('pages');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ksort()` function.
Refer from [here (offical documentation)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Comment: In this case ksort() doesn't work. I tried all functions available (sort, order by) but obviously, I can't do it alone. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove `sort($menu);` from `get_menu_links()`. Otherwise, whatever order you get in `get_pages()`, it will be ruined by the sorting.

In either case you can use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which allows to sort an array using custom compare function.

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

```
usort($menu_links, function($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
});
```

Comment: Great! Removing sort($menu) it works but then the main menu isn't sorted by 'page_order'. Using usort, without removing sort($menu) all works great, menu is sorted by page_order and values are displayed by title. Thank you mate!